# Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create cloud formation stack from below template but i am getting Template contains errors.: Template format error: YAML not well-formed error

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: A sample template
Resources:
 BFASchemaRegistry: 
  Type: AWS::Glue::Registry
  Properties: 
   Description: AWS Glue Schema Registry for BFA
   Name: BFASchemaRegistry1
   Tags: 
    -key: band
     value: bfa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **missing space** in `-key: band` and you have wrong case letters. So it should be:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: A sample template
Resources:
 BFASchemaRegistry: 
  Type: AWS::Glue::Registry
  Properties: 
   Description: AWS Glue Schema Registry for BFA
   Name: BFASchemaRegistry1
   Tags: 
    - Key: band
      Value: bfa
```

Answer (score -1):

MultiAZDatabase:
AllowedValues:
- true
- false
ConstraintDescription: Must be either true or false
Default: false
Description: Create a Multi-AZ Aurora PostgreSQL database instance
Type:String